# Make it easier to put quotes around code samples

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor

When I include `code samples` ***within a phrase*** of one of my answers, I find it hard to see that code from the rest of the phrase.
Because of this, I like to put quotes around code, like this: '`code sample`', or this: "`code sample`".

Since we already have a shortcut for making text a code sample (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), I would like to reuse that shortcut in order to put quotes around it.

That would mean the following phrase:

> my clever answer with a code sample function() call in it

would become, **with 'code sample function()' highlighted**:

- **first** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

> my clever answer with a `code sample function()` call in it

(just like today)

- **second** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

> my clever answer with a "`code sample function()`" call in it

(oh! I see now you function() call)

- **third** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

> my clever answer with a '`code sample function()`' call in it

(a more subtle way to signal the code sample part of the phrase)

- **fourth** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

> my clever answer with a code sample function() call in it

(back to normal, no more `<code>` around the text, just like today, and you can then repeat the cycle)

I have tested this feature in my own version of WMD and it works great (see [my answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-about-quoted-code-samples/2594#2594)).
But before bugging [Dana.E.Robinson](http://code.google.com/u/Dana.E.Robinson/) with a patch, I would like to see what the community thinks about this proposition.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have said in several comments that color or border is not possible.  It would be a simple CSS rule.  I've created a Greasemonkey script that does this, actually: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/greasemonkey-script-to-add-style-to-inline-code

Comment: Blast from the past :) Im tagging this status-status completed, since we eventually went with Jon's suggestion a long time ago. It doesn't fulfill your request as stated, but it solves your issue.

Comment: @balpha has it been 3 years already...

Comment: Tell me about it. The "we" in my comment is actually a lie. Back in those days, I was just a smartass running around on Meta. I still am, but these days I get payed for it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the cyclic "code sample auto-quoting" effect of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for yourself, just:

- install Git (or [**msysgit**](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) for the Windows users)
- type "`git clone http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master`": it will create a wmd directory.
- open "`wmd/wmd.js`" in an editor and replace within the function "`command.doCode()`"

:

```
chunk.findTags(/`/, /`/);
```

with:

```
chunk.findTags(/[\"']`|`/, /`[\"']|`/);
```

and:

```
else{
    chunk.startTag = chunk.endTag="";
}
```

with:

```
        else{
            if(chunk.startTag == "`"){
                chunk.startTag = "\"`";
                chunk.endTag = "`\"";
            }
            else if(chunk.startTag == "\"`"){
                chunk.startTag = "'`";
                chunk.endTag = "`'";
            }
            else{
                chunk.startTag = chunk.endTag="";
            }
        }
```

- open wmd-test.html, and start typing a few character, then repeatedly <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

I have a different preference for how code-in-text could be formatted: change the background colour for that section of the text too. That's a lot clearer than quotes in my view, as well as not interfering with code which *uses* quotes.

Comment: If the html code allowing this is supported, it can be coded following the same principle I describe in my patch.

Comment: > as well as not interfering with code which uses quotes. That is why I propose double or simple quotes. Now if your code uses both... it should be isolated in its own section, not within a phrase ;)

Comment: But even if it *does* only use one type of quote, introducing the other one makes it more confusing to read, IMO. Background colour is visually orthogonal to the characters being displayed, which is why I think it would work well.

Comment: Checking http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user right now: I am not sure any HTML tag currently accepted would allow what you want. At least, I know my quotes won't be stripped.

Comment: It would just be a matter of either accepting the relevant attribute for `<code>`, I expect. Anyway, given that this is a feature request I think it's reasonable to request the feature we (well I) think would look best, rather than one which is just a bit easier :)

Comment: i agree with skeet here, i suggested the same thing on UV a while back and it was closed with no explanation.

Comment: ++ for this suggestion. I hate seeing quoted code, and will actively edit it out in preference to backtick / `<code>` quoting. IMHO, it only leads to problems...

Comment: @Shog9: I assume you mean in terms of whole statements/expressions? I use backticks mostly to refer to just method/class names (usually with links). Do you mind those as well?

Comment: Sorry, i meant that i *like* backtick-quoted code - it's fairly easy to read, select, copy. I *don't* care for "" or '' quoted code; it makes a paragraph look cluttered, and tends to be more difficult to select without catching the quotes (and as you note, can lead to confusion if the code itself contains quotes). I don't really draw a distinction between inline expressions and inline functions/symbols when formatting.

Comment: @Jon, @Shog9: the only reason I propose quotes or double quotes is because this is the *ONLY* possible addition currently possible which will not be stripped from the end result HTML. Color or border are **better**... but **impossible** for the moment. My theory is: you do not have to copy paste *inline* code that much anyway (so quotes do not get in the way). Code to be copied should be in its own section. Again, if color or border are possible, I would drop the quotes immediately in favor of those solutions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: FYI I've posted a GreaseMonkey script that does what you're asking for: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/greasemonkey-script-to-add-style-to-inline-code

Answer (score 4):

I may be misunderstanding, but I dislike the idea of putting quotes around code.. It reminds me of all the times I've had to say "No, type it without the quotes.."

Perhaps the `inline code` could be made more visually distinct from regular text? Something like..

[image: Border around code tag]

```
blockquote p code{
    border:1px dashed #C8C8C8;
}
```

Another idea from [Jonathan Sampson's question "Code-Coloring for Inline-Code in Answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/code-coloring-for-inline-code-in-answers) which would achieve the same thing: enable syntax highlighting for inline code, the same regular code blocks. The different colours would stand out from the rest of the text.

Comment: Yes, if it's not readable simply the stylesheet should be changed.

Comment: I like that style. Simple, not intrusive, yet stands out just that extra little bit.

Comment: @dbr: the only reason I propose quotes or double quotes is because this is the ONLY possible addition currently possible which will not be stripped from the end result HTML. Color or border are **better**... but **impossible** for the moment.