# Keyboard shortcut for "code font link"?

Tags: feature-request, edits, editor, keyboard

This is related to the ["quoted code"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-about-quoted-code-samples) question, but is more to do with something I just remembered is a bit of a pain. Often, when I quote a method or class name, I'll link to the documentation, like this:

> Interestingly, .NET's [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class didn't gain a [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx) method
>   until .NET 2.0.

Doing this involves typing the name of the class/method, then selecting it and hitting Ctrl-K, then *reselecting* it to include the back ticks, then hitting Ctrl-L. It's a bit of a palaver. Any chance we could have a single keyboard shortcut to do both bits in a single hit? (So it would pop up the URL dialog, but the text would already be in a code font.)

Comment: And here I've been typing `[ \` text \` ] ( link )` all this time! :) That's a real pain on my phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Link first, then mark as code:

1. Type function name / keyword
2. Select symbol
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, enter URL. Linkify shortcut leaves link text selected.
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Ah, excellent. Will try that today and see if it feels smoother.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a overly specific thing to add a keyboard shortcut for (we'll end up turning WMD into a javascript-based emacs!..)

It's not much typing to add the ``` [``]() ``` around "Interlocked" by hand - Markdown is pretty terse..

Comment: Yes, it's terse - but adding the backticks as I go interrupts my general typing flow for some reason. (I also tend to go back to do the markup, after first writing the text.) I just thought I'd ask as it's something I do many, many times a day.

Answer (score 0):

I always just do all of the linking myself so that I can control the names of the links.

> [example]: http://example.com "This is just an example"
>
> This points to [example][], so does [this][example].

If you use the built-in editor features, it would have added the link twice `[1]:` `[2]:`, which makes it harder to edit the post, as links change.