# Inconsistent padding of inline code

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown, inline-code

Looking at the following screenshot of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452414/adding-a-prototype-to-an-object-literal/3452515#3452515), you'll notice a slight difference in padding of inline code inside normal paragraphs and that of code inside of lists:

http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/6297/inl.png

The same is true for inline code within comments appearing in my recent activity tab, e.g.

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7117/inlinecode2.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7117/inlinecode2.png)

whereas in the original comment the padding looks correct:

[alt text http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1738/inlinecode3.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1738/inlinecode3.png)

Firebug said to me that there is a CSS rule for this:

```
.comment-text code {
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

(as well as `p code` for normal paragraphs), but this isn't applied to inline code in lists, nor in the activity tab.

I can imagine that this is done to save space within lists and the recent activity tab, but at least it doesn't look consistent.

Comment: For the matter that, I personally like the lesser padding as it appears in lists more. This way the code blocks on subsequent lines doesn't flow into each other. I by the way recall a question regarding that. **Edit:** found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33709/formatting-of-inline-code-is-ugly-and-can-result-in-river-like-patterns-when-used

Comment: I prefer the lesser padding too - if a line-break is inserted before inline-code, the lines look like [having differing indentation](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/4202/screenshot20100811at122.png).

Comment: @Georg – Agreed, especially within quoting blocks, as you show.

Comment: I've discovered this as well. Now with slightly different CSS styles than mentioned in this issue here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128235/code-formatting-slightly-broken-in-lists

Comment: And this is even more obvious with `plural`s as mentioned [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/121088/3612).

Comment: @AnnaLear: This doesn't seem to have been fixed on all sites; for example, [workplace.SE] still shows this bug. (Of course, arguably, nobody should be using backticks on that site anyway, but [some people still do](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/21720).)

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs with in-line code samples in any context where they're *not* enclosed in a `<p>` tag, such as in lists, headings, etc.  It's cause by the fact that the CSS rule:

```
p code { padding: 1px 5px }
```

that adds the extra padding does not apply to those elements.

For example, compare `this code element` in a normal paragraph...

- ...with `this code element` in a list.

---

The fix I'd prefer would be to apply the padding to *all* code elements, except for those in preformatted code blocks, like this:

```
code { padding: 1px 5px }
pre code { padding: 0 }
```

---

As a work-around, at least for lists, one can add an explicit `<p>` tag at the beginning of each list item:

```
* <p> some `code` here
```

which will render like this:

- some `code` here

Note that this will also introduce some extra vertical space between the list items.  In many cases, however, this can actually be desirable anyway, especially if the list items are fairly long.

---

**Edit:** While waiting for a proper fix from the SE devs, I've added the CSS fix above to [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) 1.8.

Comment: **+1** I want this in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/q/4486/21692).

Comment: @michaelb958: It'll be in the next release, unless it gets fixed before that. :)